# Is this a good way to execute query in java?

Tags: java, database, json, connection

I am executing a query and putting result into JSONObject to return it to EXTJS page. Code works but I am not sure if this is the best or most efficient way to do it. I'll post my code please see if I need to improve it and where. I am fresh programmer so excuse obvious mistakes. Thanks in advance.

```
public JSONObject execQuery(String invoice, String id){

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();

    try{
        // get conn
        conn = DBConnect.getInstance().dbOracleConnect();  

        // create query
        sb = new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM table ");
        sb.append("WHERE rtrim(invoice) = ? AND ");
        sb.append("id = ? ");

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
        ps.setString(1, invoice); 
        ps.setString(2, id); 

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("invoice", rs.getString("invoice"));
            json.put("id", rs.getString("id"));
            json.put("name", rs.getString("name"));
            json.put("gender", rs.getString("gender"));

            jsArray.put(json);
            // out put will be like [{"invoice":"111", "id":"123", "name":"sam", "gender":"male"}, {...}]               
        }
        data.put("data", jsArray);
        // out put will be like {"data":[{"invoice":"111", "id":"123", "name":"sam", "gender":"male"}, {...}]}
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }
    finally {
        JDBCHelper.close(rs);
        JDBCHelper.close(ps);
        JDBCHelper.close(conn);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Is your connection a field? You create it and close it every query.

Comment: If `DBConnect#dbOracleConnect()` is creating a new connection each time (instead of reusing one from a pool) then you are incurring a huge amount of overhead on each and every query.

Comment: Not related to the question itself but I would prefer to declare variables whenever they are needed instead of all at the top. e.g. `JSONObject json = new JSONObject();` could be removed. Your are even creating an instance only to ignore there. That style greatly reduces readability as your method grows in size.

Comment: `StringBuffer` is `synchronized`, If you dont need synchronization then better use `StringBuilder` as its more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you need to consider in your code:

1. You are closing the connection through JDBCHelper, that means there should be a method in JDBCHelper to abstract away the details of getting a connection.
2. Since you are not creating the query dynamically, you don't need to use StringBuffer/StringBuilder. A regular String is efficient for your case.
3. The **sb** and **json** variables are initialized two times, once at the top and then again in the try block. Just declare these variables at the top and initialize them where they are used.
4. You should bring down the initialization of **json** and **jsArray** right before the while loop and initialization of **data** after the loop.

Comment: I wanted to use StringBuffer to be able to append instead of doing + . The actual query if much longer I simplified it for this post.

Comment: Thank you all for very valid points, if there are more please post it.

Answer (score 1):

Without the context, looks fine to me based on two assumptions:

1) The connection is obtained from a pool of connections. The use pattern seems to indicate that is the case. But you need to read the documentation of DBConnect and verify that.

2) The query is parameterized. You do *NOT* want the value to be concatenated directly into the SQL.  That is inefficient and insecure. Your query is set up parameterized.

Some minor comments:

1) It looks like 'conn', 'rs', 'ps' are all fields of the class.  I don't see the need.  If you set them up as local variable, you class will become stateless - easier to read and maintain. Even better to declare the variables where they are used as suggested by others.

2) StringBuffer (or StringBuilder) here is overkill.

Comment: Adding detail to the second #2: The javac compiler will optimize "start" + "middle" + "end" to "startmiddleend" when all the parts are literals.

Comment: neurite, thanks for you comment. Can you tell me more on the second comment. "2) The query is parameterized. You do NOT want the value to be concatenated directly into the SQL. That is inefficient and insecure. Your query is set up parameterized." Is using prepared statement to put parameter values to SQL query, concatenating directly into the SQL?

Comment: If not parameterized, it would be inefficient because each unique value is concatenated into a unique SQL string. The database would execute query on the fly and get no chance to optimize.  Whereas a parameterized query is seen as *one* query for all the different values by the database. Even better the database compiles it and optimizes it for better performance. Concatenated query is also insecure because of the possibility of SQL injection (i.e. the value is partial SQL and the concatenated query string is not what you want any more).

Comment: Prepared statement is not concatenated query string. "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = " + value -- this is concatenated query whereas "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = ?" is parameterized or prepared statement.

Comment: His query is already parameterized and safe against SQL injection.